# html image tag not showing image from file in XAMPP

Tags: html, css, image

I am having trouble displaying my image file on my localhost web server. I have added the html `<img>` tag without any typo error but still i cant view my image.

Below is my html code for the image:

```
<div id="circle">
   <img src="img/profile.png" alt="photo">
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
#circle {
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
}

#cirlce img {
 display: block;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

[image: The image path]

Comment: is image in same place as your html if not check the path

Comment: Yes i have checked more than 3 times.. its in the correct path @himanshu

Comment: Where is your image located, if the image and html is located in same folder then it works as `<img src="profile.png" alt="photo">` else place the folder path like `<img src="your-folder/profile.png" alt="photo">

Comment: is the file extension .PNG or any other... once check it... i think it may be different..

Comment: I have edited the question with the photos of the directory

Comment: make sure windows is not appending the file format again

Comment: try /img/profile.png instead of img/profile.png.

Comment: where is your image file and code file show your full directory snapshot

Answer (score 1):

> U can use this
>
> `<div id="circle">
>         <img src="./img/profile.png" alt="photo">
>       </div>`

Answer (score 1):

you should begin your address from inside of your main folder of your project.
for example, if the main folder of your project is called 'project', and all other folders and files are placed in this folder, and your 'img' folder is also here, your addressing is true, otherwise you must change it and begin from the place I said.

hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing the src value from profile.png to the URL link hosted in public server
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png

If loaded successfully , where is your image located.As per the existing code , profile.png should be placed along with index.html file. Else create a new folder 'images' and paste the profile.png there, changing the src value to the image folder location

```
<img src="images/profile.png" alt="photo">
```

EDIT1: 
Also make sure windows is not appending the file format to the image. It should be **profile.png** , windows by default appends.png which eventually becomes **profile.png.png** thus not fail to load the image

Comment: I have tried using the url, the image does shows, but once i save the url image into my file its not displaying the image

Comment: remove the file format in the file name and try again

Comment: Sorry can i know how to know the windows is not appending the file format?

Comment: Right click the image and select rename . change the file name from profile.png to profile (remove.png)

Comment: did you try for both the images?
Also , can you try copying the file profile.png to the location of index.html and change the src value to <img src="profile.png" alt="photo">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67714/discussion-between-user3592479-and-raaj-lokanathan).

Comment: @Raaj let us join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67714/discussion-between-user3592479-and-raaj-lokanathan

Comment: Try by giving full image path using localhost

Answer (score 0):

Your source path is not correct replace `<img src="img/profile.png" alt="photo">` with `<img src=".img/profile.png" alt="photo">`

Comment: Sorry can I know what's the difference between this 2 line of codes?

Comment: . represents current directory

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.. It was with the web server problem.. So now it's working